# Sound beats mathematical expression

Tags: waves, acoustics, superposition

I am reading about sound beats. According to the superposition principle, if at a certain position the two waves are given by, let say,

$$\ y_a(t)=Asin(2\pi f_at)$$
$$\ y_b(t)=-Asin(2\pi f_bt)$$

then the total wave will be
$$\ y_a(t)+y_b(t)=[2Asin(\frac{1}{2}(2\pi)( f_a-f_b)t]cos\frac{1}{2}(2\pi)( f_a+f_b)t$$

Now, my question is, when grouping the terms in this expression, why do you say that the $sin(\frac{1}{2}(2\pi)( f_a-f_b)t$ is the amplitude factor and not the $cos\frac{1}{2}(2\pi)( f_a+f_b)t$. How can you know that it's the sine not the cosine that is varying the amplitude.

Edit: my real question is that why is it the $f_a-f_b$ not the $f_a+f_b$ term that is modulating the amplitude.

Image source: university physics by young and freedman.

[image: beats]

Comment: Both of them are varying the amplitude, but the sine term in this particular case is varying it only _slowly_ for two close frequencies (such that $f_a-f_b$ is small).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Can you convert the picture of the text into typed-out, formatted text? It makes the content index-able by search engines, and shows up better on different devices' displays. For formulae, try [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not particularly relevant that it is the $\sin$ term rather than the $\cos$ term, except in so far as that's how the expansion of the functions work.

Given we start with the expression

$$\begin{align}
y(t) &= y_a(t) + y_b(t)\\
     &= 2A\sin\left(2\pi \frac{f_a - f_b}{2}t\right)
          \cos\left(2\pi \frac{f_a + f_b}{2}t\right)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

The thing to look at is what this looks like when $f_a$ is very close to $f_b$, and in particular when $\left|f_a - f_b)\right| \ll (f_a + f_b)$.

In this case it's useful to define

$$
\begin{align}
f &= \frac{f_a + f_b}{2}\\
\Delta f &= \frac{f_a - f_b}{2}
\end{align}
$$

And $\left|\Delta f\right| \ll f$

So our expression now looks like

$$y(t) = 2A\sin(2\pi\Delta f t)\cos(2\pi ft)$$

Depending on how close in frequency $f_a$ & $f_b$ are, $\Delta f$ can be very small indeed: it can be zero in fact.  But $f$ is not going to be zero unless both $f_a$ & $f_b$ are zero (let's quietly assume that $f_a \ge 0$ & $f_b \ge 0$, which we can safely do).

So, if these are audio frequencies, what this is going to *sound* like is a tone of frequency $f\approx f_a \approx f_b$, changing slowly in volume at a frequency of $\Delta f$ which may be very small.

That's why it's that term which is thought of as modulating the amplitude.

Here are two pictures which, I hope, make it clear why it is the difference term which should be thought of as doing the modulating.  First of all here is a second of $\sin (200 \pi t)$: a $100\,\mathrm{Hz}$ sine wave:

[image: 100Hz for a second]

Now here is a second of $\sin(200\pi t) + \sin(204\pi t)$: a waveform made up of $100\,\mathrm{Hz}$ and $102\,\mathrm{Hz}$ sine waves:

[image]

I think it is extremely obvious that this is a high-frequency wave being modulated by a low-frequency wave.

(Note that both of these pictures have some artifacts in due to my inadequate plotting skills.)

---

In the original version of this answer I thought the question was why the $\sin$ term rather than a $\cos$ term is doing the modulating, and I had a rather grotty paragraph showing that you could make it be either.  Here is a cleaned-up version of that, for posterity.

First of all, define $\omega_a = 2\pi f_a$ & $\omega_b = 2\pi f_b$: this is just to get rid of a bunch of annoying factors of $2\pi$: $\omega$ is the *angular frequency*.  To make things simpler I'll also make $A=1$: again this is just to make this term go away so I have less to write.

Now the original expression looks like

$$\sin(\omega_a t) - \sin(\omega_b t)$$

And if we assume $\omega_a \approx \omega_b$ we can write $\omega_a = \omega +\Delta\omega$ & $\omega_b = \omega - \Delta\omega$.  Then the above becomes

$$\sin(\omega t + \Delta\omega t) - \sin(\omega t - \Delta\omega t)
= 2\sin(\Delta\omega t)\cos(\omega t)$$

by the double-angle formula for $\sin$.

But what if, instead, we consider

$$
\begin{align}
\sin(\omega t + \Delta\omega t) - \sin(\omega t - \Delta\omega t - \pi)
&= \sin(\omega t + \Delta\omega t) + \sin(\omega t - \Delta\omega t)\\
&= 2\cos(\Delta\omega t)\sin(\omega t)
\end{align}
$$

This is just offsetting one of the terms by a constant of $\pi$: acoustically this is the same thing.  But now using the same double-angle formula we find the term doing the modulating is $\cos$ not $\sin$: it doesn't make any difference, in fact.

Comment: thank you for your answer, and sorry for my late reply. I think I phrased my question badly. My point is that I'm not confusing why it's the sine or the cosine at all. My point is why is the fa-fb/2, not the fa+fb/2 that is modulating the amplitude. Also I wonder whether there are some typos in your answer.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer to your question. The key point is that $f_a$ and $f_b$ are implicitly taken to be very close when talking about beat frequency.

Comment: I have added pictures which I hope made it clearer.  I can't see typos but that does not mean there are none: you should be able to suggest an edit to fix any I think.

Comment: @tfb thanks for the picture. Along with Cort's answer I think I understand it now. About the typos, I'm not sure whether you should put a + there in between the sine and the cosine or not, as I understand that it should be a multiplication? Also, shouldn't it be abs(f1-f2) DIVIDED BY TWO that you are trying to compare with the average between f1 and f2. I really appreciate your effort!

Comment: @JoisBack: Oh, yes, there were some really obvious mistakes!  Very sorry about that.  I have, I hope, fixed them now, and I've also rationalised the 'why-it's-sin-not-cos' bit and moved it to the end as it was not what you were asking.  You might want to check that it still makes sense (ie that you still want to accept it as the answer).

Answer (score 1):

It's convention.  It's how we typically define modulation.

You are absolutely correct that mathematically, it doesn't matter if you are modulating around $\frac{f_a-f_b}{2}$ or $\frac{f_a+f_b}{2}$.  However, when we talk about modulation, we will always refer to the slower frequency as the one that is modulating the higher frequency.

In this particular example, the difference is arbitrary. In other cases, it will not be.  When we look at how we use modulation in practical applications, its virtually always using a low frequency signal to modulate a high frequency carrier (with a fixed amplitude).  Doing so provides lots of convenient mathematical properties which we leverage.  Doing it the other way (modulating a low frequency carrier with a high frequency signal) just doesn't provide the behaviors we want.  It provides other behaviors.

For example, one well known use of modulation is to modulate the audio-frequency signals from a radio station into a frequency band which can be easily transmitted through airspace.  In such cases, the signal is in the low kHz, and the carrier is in high kHz to MHz.

So when your wave question showing beats can be written in a form which looks like modulation, we'll always declare the low frequency side to be modulating the amplitude.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation. One question. What do you mean by 'just doesn't provide the behaviors we want'?

Comment: [This answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2493/why-carrier-signal-cant-have-frequency-less-than-message-signal) gives a few examples.  Long story short, we modulate to work around some physical limitation.  One specific feature we use a lot is that it "moves" the signal to a different band.  This can be done to avoid collisions (i.e. different radio stations on different carrier frequencies) or to work around physical limitations (such as passing low frequency signals past a decoupling capacitor).

Comment: Signing also provides an interesting counterexample.  While we typically think of the low frequency input as the signal and the high frequency input as a carrier frequency, with tremulo we do the exact opposite.  We have a high frequency signal (the melody), and we modulate it by a low frequency (on the order of a few hertz).  Like before, this modulation is done because it generates the beats pattern you showed above, and it makes the sound feel "richer" because it sounds like there's more voice.  However, I believe this is the exception that proves the rule.